# scrartcl / section / itemize: Why empty page?

Tags: page-breaking

I am quite sure it is my fault, but I can't explain this behaviour of LaTeX using the `scrartcl` class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,onecolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\title{Test}

\author{Sebastian}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Links}
Lesenswerte Artikel und weiterführende Informationen:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \url{http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-30199004} (empfehlenswerter Überblick)
    \item \url{http://allafrica.com/stories/201408280138.html} (LCL Ebola Awareness)
    \item \url{http://www.actalliance.org/resources/alerts_and_situation_reports/Alert12_2014_WestAfrica_Ebola.pdf} (ActAlliance-Alert vom April 2014)
    \item \url{http://help-liberia.com/ebola/ebola-in-liberia-news} (Sehr übersichtliche deutschsprachige Webseite mit ausführlichen Informationen zum Ebolaausbruch in Liberia)
\end{itemize}
So.

\section{Bilder}
\rule{373.44246pt}{527.93196pt} \\
\noindent Quelle: MOHSW Monrovia7Liberia 2014.

\end{document}
```

Upon compiling, everything looks fairly ok, except that a blank page is added between section one and two. I just don't know why - even the log file looks ok.

Comment: Hi and welcome, try making the picture smaller. `.5\textwidth`

Comment: we can't see the image so can't test can you replace `\includegraphics` by `\rule{3cm}{5cm}` or whatever size shows the problem.

Comment: Runaway argument?
{http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-30199004 (empfehlenswerter Übe\ETC

Comment: I have tried various sizes of rule in place of includegraphics and always get 1 page or 2, never 3 with a blank page. `\rule{\textwidth}{6.32578cm}` and smaller gives 1 page `\rule{\textwidth}{6.32579cm}` and larger gives 2 pages

Comment: Did you fix the missing closing brace? Does that make any difference?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Missing closing brace is a typo - is correct on my computer. Thanks though. @David: The logfile tells me that the graphic was resized to this: `\rule{373.44246pt}{527.93196pt}`

Comment: @Johannes_B: Your first comment made me wonder if the picture might be too large, and that idea works. However I still don't know why. I would assume that scrartcl calculates the width and height correct?

Comment: Well, i can't say what is really oing on. Convert the pt values in mm `\rule{140mm}{200mm}`. I bet you picture is in portrait mode? Load package `showframe` to check the page margins.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks for the hint. The picture is in portrait, you're right. It is a tiny bit too long - so little I couldn't even see it in the PDF. Shouldn't that give me an overfull-error in the log? However, problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: There should be an overfull box message (those are not errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were just unlucky.

With

```
\rule{373.44246pt}{505pt}
```

It takes 2 pages, with section 2 and the image on page 2.

With

```
\rule{373.44246pt}{510pt}
```

It takes 3 pages, with blank page 2.

However TeX does warn in that case

```
Overfull \vbox (4.90276pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
```

Normally an overfull vbox does what you might expect and overflow the bottom margin, but here it gets caught in the page breaking decisions around the section head and an extra page gets thrown which is probably a latex bug really.

I have a feeling Frank analysed a similar case in an answer here not so long ago...

Answer (score 3):

You did not do anything wrong, it is a (documented) deficiency of TeX or a bug in `hyperref` depending how you like to look at it. If you replace `hyperref`by the `url` package in your example the pages comes out as expected.

So what happens?

- `hyperref` adds a lot of `\pdfdest` commands into the page one of which is `\pdfdest name{section.<number>} xyz` as part of a heading (e.g., `\section` in your case)
- now these commands generate "whatits" nodes in the output and "whatsits" are not discarded at a page break
- however penalty and glues are
- so if `hyperref` adds `\pdfdest ... \nobreak` and the page break happens to be taken just in front of it (as it is the case in the example as the section and the material following is a single block that is too big), then `\pdfdest` will be later moved to the top of the current page (next one to be formed) but the `\nobreak` (which is a penalty) will vanish because TeX has not seen any boxes (eg lines of text yet)
- next TeX sees the first line of text (e.g., the text of the `\section` title) and that being the first box on the page it adds `\topskip` glue in front of it, thus the page now looks like `\pdfdest ... \glue (from topskip)
- so this glue from `\topskip` is no longer the first thing on the page and according to TeX rules a glue is a valid page break if it is preceeded by non-discardable item (e.g., a "whatsit") which is the case now.
- so we have (a very bad) page break possibility at the very beginning of the page which is not there without `hyperref`
- but since the section and its first line is larger than a page TeX doesn't find a pagebreak after it so resorts to using the one at the very beginning of the page
- without that breakpoint, TeX wouldn't find any place to break at all so would resort to make an overfull box (i.e. break after the section and the "picture" at the first possible place)

You can watch all this unfold by adding

```
\tracingpages=1 \tracingonline=1
```

in the preamble. The the extra break points become immediately visible in lines such as

```
% t=31.90276 plus 1.86108 g=538.0 b=10000 p=-300 c=100000#
% t=615.80687 plus 9.02771 minus 0.86108 g=538.0 b=* p=0 c=*
[1{c:/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
%% goal height=538.0, max depth=5.0
% t=0.0 g=538.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=560.83472 plus 1.86108 g=538.0 b=* p=0 c=*
[2]
%% goal height=538.0, max depth=5.0
% t=560.83472 plus 1.86108 g=538.0 b=* p=0 c=*#

Overfull \vbox (22.83472pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []

[3]
```

you can nicely see the breakpoint at `t=0.0` when page 2 is formed, the next possible breakpoit (`t=560...`) is already too late so the first one is taken. Then for page 3 the first breakpoint is this time `t=560...` (no surprise as we are looking at the same material with just one breakpoint removed) so now TeX takes it and reports an overfull page

Basically (as a summary) TeX code should really not add "whatsit" nodes in vertical mode at all, but should do that only in horizontal mode (e.g., at the beginning of the next paragraph). The problem though is that LaTeX's paragraphing machinery doesn't provide any support for that and without an underlying support structure that is bound to be hard/impossible. (An not that anybody thinks I point the finger at @HeikoOberdiek, the `color` package from the core LaTeX distribution, for example, has the same issue really as it also has to issue "whatsits" and they can change the page breaking in a similar way.)

For LaTeX3 we have experimented with providing a "galley" structure that offers this support but to make this usable all packages would need to use its interfaces otherwise you end up with a mixed batch of nodes on the main vertical list and things would go out of hand.

A possible alternative for LaTeX2e would be to make `\topskip` equal to `\baselineskip` add then a rule or a box in front of the `\pdfdest` and some appropriate amount of negative skip (including fiddeling with `\prevdepth` in the right way). That way this box would trigger the `\topskip` addition and thus the `\topskip` glue would appear again at the very top of the page and thus not generate a valid breakpoint. The negative skip would cancel its effect and the next box would be added not using `\topskip` but `\baselineskip`.

Just a rough sketch and possibly full of holes, but thats about the only way I could see this working in 2e.

ps Your example is not really minimal ... you can drop a lot of the packages without loss and others by simplifying the input (eg use plan text not utf8 or german). By doing that the "culprit" package could have been perhaps identified upfront.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek  any thoughts on whether or not that could be improved in hyperref?